# Kotlin serialize subclass: "Polymorphic serializer was not found"

Tags: kotlin, testing, serialization, polymorphism

I'm trying to serialize a subclass' instance but the output is unexpected.

Here is the code (second test differs from first one only at `cc: ${c as Child}`):

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import org.junit.Test

class SerializeTest {
    @Test
    fun one() {
        println("test: one")
        val c: Parent = Child("HI")
        println("c: $c")
        val en = Json.encodeToString(c)
        println("json: $en")
        val de: Parent = Json.decodeFromString(en)
        println("de: $de")
    }

    @Test
    fun two() {
        println("test: two")
        val c: Parent = Child("HI")
        println("c: $c, cc: ${c as Child}")
        val en = Json.encodeToString(c)
        println("json: $en")
        val de: Parent = Json.decodeFromString(en)
        println("de: $de")
    }
}

@Serializable
sealed class Parent(val integer: Int)

@Serializable
class Child (val string: String): Parent(0)
```

The output:

```
test: one
c: com.example.CC@415b0b49
json: {"type":"com.example.CC","integer":0,"string":"HI"}
de: com.example.CC@3e6104fc
test: two
c: com.example.CC@62010f5c, cc: com.example.CC@62010f5c
json: {"integer":0,"string":"HI"}

Exception: Polymorphic serializer was not found for missing class discriminator ('null')
JSON input: {"integer":0,"string":"HI"}
...
```

The first test runs fine but the second test fails with an exception.

Can anyone explain why the casting: `c as Child` (which compiler is already aware of implicitly) causes the encode function to omit `type` for the second test?

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Because it is impracticable for the library to work any other way.

---

#### That's how it works

On one level you can say: `type` is omitted because that's how the library is written. This behaviour is [clearly documented](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md#sealed-classes).

> When serializing polymorphic class hierarchies you must ensure that the compile-time type of the serialized object is a polymorphic one, not a concrete one.

#### Serializing child objects

But why does it work this way? Well, think how the `encodeToString` function works. When called, it only knows the type of the object it is asked to serialize. If that type is `Child` it can straightforwardly serialize the object as a `Child` and the job is done.

So what if the library was written to try and discover `Child` was a subclass of `Parent`, and serialize accordingly? This might not in fact be possible, because `Child` and `Parent` might prescribe different serializers from the automatically generated one. If they clashed, how would the library know which one to choose? It couldn't easily guarantee compatibility with both.

Further, `Child` could have several parent classes. Which one or ones should it serialize for?

All of these problems can be avoided if you don't try and support such a feature.

#### Serializing parent objects

Now when the type `encodeToString` sees is `Parent` then the function can easily discover that it is dealing with a sealed class (there's a simple property for that) and then add the `type` discriminator to facilitate polymorphic serialization.

As you may know, if `Parent` is not sealed it will not add the type discriminator automatically. For that you have to register `Child` for polymorphic serialization. Hopefully you can see that registering classes in this way also gives `encodeToString` a straightforward way of knowing if it needs to add a type discriminator.

All-in-all, the Kotlin team have made a practical choice for how their library works.